# How to set mysql username in dockerfile

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile

When installing mysql in ubuntu with `apt-get install mysql-server`, the mysql username and password are asked during the installation.

But when using a dockerfile to build a mysql image, how can the username and password be provided?

I tried using the dockerfile as follows:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
apt-get update
apt-get install -y mysql-server
```

But when building the image, I found out we can login in the mysql without username and password.

How can I set the username and password when I use dockerfile to build my images?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you take a look at the official Docker MySQL image [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/5.6/Dockerfile#L26), you will discover how they did it using [debconf-set-selections](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/fr/man1/debconf-set-selections.1.html).

The relevant instructions are:

```dockerfile
RUN { \
        echo mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/data-dir select ''; \
        echo mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/root-pass password ''; \
        echo mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/re-root-pass password ''; \
        echo mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/remove-test-db select false; \
    } | debconf-set-selections \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y mysql-server
```

`debconf-set-selections` is a tool that allows you to prepare the answers for the questions that will be asked during the later installation.

Comment: Thanks! I found that this needed an additional line as described [here](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker/issues/58#issuecomment-47995343). A complete, build-tested example is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39376045/577088).

Answer (score 3):

[tutumcloud/mysql](https://github.com/tutumcloud/mysql)

Dockerfile

```
ADD run.sh /run.sh

ENV MYSQL_USER=admin \
    MYSQL_PASS=**Random** \
    ON_CREATE_DB=**False** \
    REPLICATION_MASTER=**False** \
    REPLICATION_SLAVE=**False** \
    REPLICATION_USER=replica \
    REPLICATION_PASS=replica
```

run.sh

```
StartMySQL ()
{
    /usr/bin/mysqld_safe ${EXTRA_OPTS} > /dev/null 2>&1 &
    # Time out in 1 minute
    LOOP_LIMIT=60
    for (( i=0 ; ; i++ )); do
        if [ ${i} -eq ${LOOP_LIMIT} ]; then
            echo "Time out. Error log is shown as below:"
            tail -n 100 ${LOG}
            exit 1
        fi
        echo "=> Waiting for confirmation of MySQL service startup, trying ${i}/${LOOP_LIMIT} ..."
        sleep 1
        mysql -uroot -e "status" > /dev/null 2>&1 && break
    done
}
CreateMySQLUser()
{
    if [ "$MYSQL_PASS" = "**Random**" ]; then
        unset MYSQL_PASS
    fi

    PASS=${MYSQL_PASS:-$(pwgen -s 12 1)}
    _word=$( [ ${MYSQL_PASS} ] && echo "preset" || echo "random" )
    echo "=> Creating MySQL user ${MYSQL_USER} with ${_word} password"

    mysql -uroot -e "CREATE USER '${MYSQL_USER}'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '$PASS'"
    mysql -uroot -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '${MYSQL_USER}'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION"
    echo "=> Done!"
    echo "========================================================================"
    echo "You can now connect to this MySQL Server using:"
    echo ""
    echo "    mysql -u$MYSQL_USER -p$PASS -h<host> -P<port>"
    echo ""
    echo "Please remember to change the above password as soon as possible!"
    echo "MySQL user 'root' has no password but only allows local connections"
    echo "========================================================================"
}
StartMySQL
CreateMySQLUser
```

.....helpful for u

Comment: In general, be very careful with `mysql -uroot -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '${MYSQL_USER}'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION"`

Comment: for two reasons. you just gave them rights to everything (well that is about the only reason you need) ... but also, be careful with WITH GRANT OPTION