# MySQL in Docker frozen at root password config

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile

I have the next dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -y apache2 mysql-server mysql-client
```

After, Docker build asking me the password root:

```
While not mandatory, it is highly recommended that you set a password for the
MySQL administrative "root" user.

If this field is left blank, the password will not be changed.

New password for the MySQL "root" user:
```

I enter the password, but, simply it stays in that state.

Can I install mysql this way?, I do not want to install it automatically

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Docker way is "one container for one process". 
You need one container for apache and one for mysql.
You can use [official php image](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/) and [official mysql image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)

for linking the containers i recommend use docker-compose

Comment: I planned to use Supervisor... which option is better? docker-compose or supervisor?

Comment: we used to supervisord later, but now we use separate containers. it give some advantages. We can use official images and updates, update only one part of cluster, fast rollback to previos version of container.

Comment: This is really very interesting, I try docker-compose

Comment: While this provides a workaround this does not answer the question.

Answer (score 24):

The accepted answer may be true in some abstract sense, but it's completely irrelevant to the matter at hand. You need a way to specify the password statically. And unless you are using the [official image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/), you'll need that whether or not you follow the "one process, one container" dogma.

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32146887/577088) tells how, but it leaves out a key setting: you still have to tell `debconf` to use the `Noninteractive` front-end, as described [here](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker/issues/58#issuecomment-47995343).

Here's an example of a working `Dockerfile` based on the above.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER Jonathan Strange <jstrange@norrell.edu>
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y apt-utils \                                           
    && { \
        echo debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive; \
        echo mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/data-dir \
            select ''; \
        echo mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/root-pass \
            password 'JohnUskglass'; \
        echo mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/re-root-pass \
            password 'JohnUskglass'; \
        echo mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/remove-test-db \
            select true; \
    } | debconf-set-selections \
    && apt-get install -y mysql-server apache2 python python-django \
        python-celery rabbitmq-server git
```

This is not too terribly different from what the [official `Dockerfile`](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/ad625c64a06e16683e997e5a0147508d115f4989/8.0/Dockerfile) does -- though they handle the actual password config somewhat differently.

Some people have had success by [setting the DEBIAN_FRONTEND](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker/issues/58#issuecomment-57900765) environment variable to `noninteractive`, like so:

```
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
```

However, that doesn't seem to work in all cases. Using `debconf` directly has proven more reliable for me.

Comment: Inside container. I couldnt start mysql console using mysql -u root -proot giving 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2).

Comment: @Vinujan.S that's a different problem. If it's not already asked as a question on this site, you should ask it as a new question.

Comment: I have fixed the issue later. But I changed the mechanism to have seperate container for mysql. Thank you for the response. really appreciate it.

Comment: I wonder what the point of the empty string '' is in the 2nd echo command. It causes echo to output a blank between the word 'select' and the newline, because echo finds an empty 4th command line argument. But is this blank really relevant to debconf-set-selections?

Comment: I don't know but it's there in the official MySQL dockerfile too, so I'd guess so!

Comment: This part is troubling: "Some people have had success by setting the DEBIAN_FRONTEND environment variable to noninteractive, like so:

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

However, that doesn't seem to work in all cases". Isn't reproducibility a key promise of containers, i.e. that the result is always the same, regardless of who executes the container / buildfile? (And btw, the empty string part from my last comment can be left out - same debconf behaviour)

Comment: I suspect the explicit blank line is there to indicate that the absence is intended. And note the difference between an image and a Dockerfile. A particular image will always be the same, but different builds of the same Dockerfile may differ.

Comment: A simple example is when you use the "latest" tag. Docker can't prevent providers from making interface-breaking changes! It has certainly happened to me.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case sendarle's answer was not very clear, add environment DEBIAN_FRONTEND such as shown below to your Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive   

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y mysql-server mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev 
   --no-install-recommends \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

Comment: Inside container. I couldnt start mysql console using mysql -u root -proot giving ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2).